# update sql with case and update the value whichever case is right

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE users SET log = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END WHERE r_id = 1
```

This updates timestamp of 2 rows one which is previous log=1 and the current log=1 .How can I update only the current log=1 ?

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `sno` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `r_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `log` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) 



INSERT INTO `users` (`sno`, `id`, `r_id`, `log`, `last_login`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1', 0, '2014-05-13 14:44:09'),
(2, '2', '1', 0, '2014-05-13 14:45:07'),
(3, '3', '1', 0, '2014-05-13 14:44:09'),
(4, '4', '1', 0, '2014-05-13 14:44:09'),
(5, '5', '1', 0, '2014-05-13 15:19:23'),
(6, '6', '2', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(7, '7', '3', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Answer :

```
UPDATE users SET log = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END,last_login = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN now()  ELSE last_login END WHERE r_id = 1
```

Comment: did not get what you are trying to do could you explain a bit on the update part ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty   I am trying to update log=1 to user who just logged in and update his last_login timestamp but not others thats it .In my case 2 rows timestamp is updated .THE previous log=1 row and now the user who just logged in his row.I just want the user who logged in just now his row to update timestamp not the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two conditions in the `case` but only one `then`.  The following is speculation on what you want:

```
UPDATE users
    SET log = (CASE WHEN id = '2' AND last_login = now() THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
               END)
    WHERE r_id = '1';
```

Do note that comparing a value such as `last_login` to `now()` is *very* dangerous.  You will likely never get a match.  Perhaps something like:

```
UPDATE users
    SET log = (CASE WHEN id = '2' AND
                         last_login >= now() - interval 1 second
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
               END)
    WHERE r_id = '1';
```

EDIT:

If you want to update only the last row in `users` meeting these conditions, perhaps you want:

```
UPDATE users
    SET log = (CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    WHERE r_id = '1'
    ORDER BY last_login DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hello Sir.Its been a while .Thanks for the response but I am not matching the last_login .I just want to update the current user who logs in ,his timestamp value.

Comment: I am trying to update log=1 to user who just logged in and update his last_login timestamp but not others thats it .In my case 2 rows timestamp is updated .THE previous log=1 row and now the user who just logged in his row.I just want the user who logged in just now his row to update timestamp not the previous or any other row's timepstamp.

Comment: @jason . . . I assume the real answer to your question is to use a trigger, based on when someone logs in (say when the login record is inserted into the login table).

Comment: yes exactly but if there is another user with same r_id then the rest of the users log=0 and user who logs-in will be log=1 and only his timestamp will be updated not others

Comment: basically 2 rows are updating its timestamp if there is a match of r_id between 2 rows

Comment: Since `last_login timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Hi Gordon .Can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157569/get-rows-based-on-expiry-time  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` is a function and should not be in quotes:

```
UPDATE users SET log = CASE WHEN id = '2' THEN 1 AND last_login = NOW() ELSE 0 END WHERE r_id = '1'
```

By being in quotes you are telling MySQL the value is the literal string "now()" instead of the function.

Comment: This  executes but it does not update the value log or the timestamp

Comment: How do I update the timestamp for the case which is true without updating timestamp for other last_login ?